# Is it possible to set same port work with http and https?

Tags: networking, apache2, proxy, nodejs

I've nodejs application which port number is `3001` and this app working with http but not work with https. On apache server, set the revers proxy for `80` or `443` to `5001` and set revers proxy for 3001 also.

```
http://<domain>:3001/socket.io/socket.js   ---> Work

https://<domain>:3001/socket.io/socket.js   ---> Not Work(Secure Connection Failed or This site can’t be reached)
```

Here I need to know same port(`3001`) is work with `http` and `https` ?

Any solution for that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with nodejs apps, but in all cases you can use `stunnel4` to redirect http to https.

Comment: but our requirement is to work both http and https so redirect not option for me :) In general case it is possible ?

Comment: If http port is open in the firewall, it will be accessible.

Comment: Port 80, 443 and 3001 are open to all but second https url which not work as above

Comment: I will write an answer and if you want you can try it.

Comment: @SpasSpasov Sure Man

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50085/discussion-between-rgg-and-spas-spasov).

Comment: Please, avoid cross posting ( http://serverfault.com/questions/820621/is-it-possible-to-set-same-port-work-with-http-and-https ) . Have you checked these similar posts from SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453782/nodejs-http-and-https-over-same-port , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313308/binding-http-and-https-traffic-on-the-same-port-in-node-js

Comment: @user.dz i check above url it contains coding  level and haproxy solution but i need to change on apache server  only

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible to run HTTP and HTTPS on the same port.

When using HTTPS the connection uses the SSL/TLS protocol from the very start. There is no possibility for the client to start transmitting using plain HTTP.

The SSL/TLS standard doesn't provide for a way to drop back to HTTP if plaintext communication is detected on the port.

Comment: So that developer set another port 9001 for https and 3001 for http,  Now issue is that http+3001 working file. using https+9001 url working directly. Can we redirect https+3001->9001 using apache2 proxy ?

Comment: You would not be able to run both the redirect and the HTTP service on port 3001. You can't listen for both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port regardless of what your internal setup is.

Comment: Can we do like if  https+3001 --> 9001 redirect before the apache server  and for http not changes. here my case 3001 port common for http and https (able to open https+9001 URL working fine).

Comment: If `https` working properly, why you need `http`?

Comment: No, http working properly but https not because same port(3001), requirements is to work both, pls suggest me ones more

Comment: No unfortunately you cannot do as suggested a couple of comments ago. At the level of network communication where you would need to redirect a port, you would not know whether HTTP or HTTPS is being used yet. While you might be able to buffer and sniff the data, it would be both complicated and affect security.

Comment: You absolutely can do this if you write the http(s) server. It's very easy to distinguish a TLS client handshake "hello" from a plaintext HTTP request, you only need to inspect the first byte (== 0x16 (TLS) or not). However, it would be difficult or impossible to combine that with most HTTP server implementations, as they don't typically allow you to pass them existing connections and buffers. The more important question is why would you want to do this, it's not generally a good idea.

Comment: If it is not possible how does this nodejs library do it? https://github.com/mscdex/httpolyglot

Comment: Well that looks like a pretty neat solution.  It would have to remember state enough that communication could continue, and I imagine a client would not be able to mix HTTP and HTTPS requests to the same server

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how they did it, but the developers in my company did exactly what @thomasrutter says you can't do: We use a non standard TCP port (so not 80, nor 443) e.g. 8080 and on that port if you send a http request it redirects you to https on the same port 8080. They did it with nginx and did not achieve this with apache2!

Edit: does seem to do it in nginx witha 497 error code and your browser does the rest: https://ma.ttias.be/force-redirect-http-https-custom-port-nginx/

Comment: It's impossible to do it at the network layer, ie *without* integrating the functionality into your TLS wrapper code (or deep inspection of same with buffering).   If you do have the ability to integrate this functionality into your TLS code, to detect an incoming conversation that's not a valid handshake to see if it's plain HTTP, then yes.  It's a kludge, whose security implications I haven't fully thought through, but it's doable at that layer.  In your case, if the only possible HTTP interaction is a redirect to HTTPS, then at first glance I can't see any security issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  This exact same question was asked in 2014 on NodeJS GitHub (by none other than Andrew Kelley of Zig fame): "ability to serve both HTTP and HTTPS on the same port" -> https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/121

A responder recommended this very simple (!) NodeJS package: https://github.com/mscdex/httpolyglot

Roughly, it works by inspecting the first byte of a new connection.  If non-printable char, treat as SSL/TLS/HTTPS, else tread as HTTP.  Very impressive.  More details here: https://github.com/mscdex/httpolyglot/issues/3